# How to use multiple contexts for single DB, without violating dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Let's say I have a method that loads some entities from database, makes an API call for each, gets a token from a third party and saves them.
The API call is critical so we want each call to be logged into db instantly.
So I put `context.SaveChanges` in `CriticalAPI`, to save each log separately.
The problem is that this `SaveChanges` also saves `Posts` entities modified in `Method()`.
I want `CriticalAPI` to only save logs, not other objects. One way is to create another context and use in that method, but it violates dependency injection because I should instantiate a new context in my method.
What is the correct way to achieve this requirements?

```
public void Method(){
    var entities = context.Posts.Where(/* something */).ToList();
    foreach (var entity in entities){
         var result = CriticalAPI(entity.Id);
         entity.Token = result;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}

public int CriticalAPI(int id){
    var token = /* do something critical */
    context.Logs.Add(new Log(){
         entityId = id
    });
    context.SaveChanges();
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Just define context factory interface and inject the factory. Then use the factory anywhere you need to create new context instance:

```
interface IDbContextFactory {
    DbContext CreateContext();
}

//...

public void Method() {
    using (var context = contextFactory.CreateContext()) {
        context.Posts.Where(/* something */)
            .ForEach(entity => {
                var result = CriticalAPI(entity.Id);
                entity.Token = result;
            });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public int CriticalAPI(int id) {
    using (var context = contextFactory.CreateContext()) {
        var token = /* do something critical */
        context.Logs.Add(new Log(){
            entityId = id
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
        return token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great way to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.AsNoTracking()` method after when you're calling `context.Posts` and the entity will not track changes.

```cs
public void method(){
    var entities = context.Posts
             .AsNoTracking() //  <---- add this Method here
             .Where(/* something */).ToList();
    foreach (var entity in entities){
         var result = CriticalAPI(entity.Id);
         entity.Token = result;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

You could alternatively create an ENTIRELY separate dbContext for Logs, and you would set and save that context.

Comment: I want Posts to be saved, but not in the middle of the loop and by CriticalAPI().
I want alll Posts to be saved at the end of method()

Comment: Then I think you would want to create an entirely seperate dbContext for logs, where the only `DbSet` is Logs.  You'd remove that whatever context Post is in, and then you can save your Logs independently of Posts.